# calling JSONP with headers from angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, jsonp, twitter-oauth

```
    $http({
      method: 'JSONP',
      url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?screen_name=%40name',
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNxXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      }
    }).then(function (data) {
         console.log(data);
       });
```

I am trying to get my followers list from twitter.whats wrong with my code?

thanks for all help.

Comment: jsonp doesn't support request headers

Comment: @charlietfl :Thanks for the quick reply.Then how i can i pass the authorization?

Comment: what happens when you use GET?

Comment: @charlietfl :

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?screen_name=%name. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400"

getting error

Comment: then you need to use a proxy on your server

Comment: @charlietfl : OPTIONS is failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONP` can not be called with headers.We must use `GET` to pass headers.